# How to rename Mounted Drive Name in MFC(VC++ )?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to rename Mounted Drive Name programatically in MFC(VC++ ) ?
I am using WNetAddConnection2 for mounting drives, now i want to rename them programatically .
How i can do that ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SetVolumeLabel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365560%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Swapnil: I have no idea about those. Note that you might want to make your question more specific if it is about network drives.